# Memory issue with django-imagekit

Tags: python, django, django-imagekit, imagekit

I am working on a news aggregator and use django-imagekit to create news article thumbnails.

The application is hosted on Heroku. Over time, I noticed the application consumes more and more memory. Currently, there are about 8000 images in the database and the application consumes about 3 times more memory in comparison to a staging application which has about 100 images in the database.

I believe the problem has to do with django-imagekit. If I call the original images in the templates, instead of images processed by django-imagekit, the memory drops down to a normal level.

The models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    …
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, blank=True, null=True, related_name='+', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    …


class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    …
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/photos/%Y/%m/%d', max_length=255)
    …

    thumb = ImageSpecField(source='photo',
            processors=[resize.ResizeToFit(131, 131),],
            options={'quality': 90})
    thumbnail_image = ImageSpecField(source='photo',
            processors=[resize.ResizeToFill(100, 100),],
            options={'quality': 90})
    news_small = ImageSpecField(source='photo',
            processors=[resize.ResizeToFill(125, 94),],
            format='JPEG',
            options={'quality': 90})
    …
```

Template example:

```
<a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ item.photo.news_small.url }}" alt=""></a>
```

Settings.py

```
redis_url = urlparse(os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'))
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': '%s:%s' % (redis_url.hostname, redis_url.port),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'DB': 0,
            'PARSER_CLASS': 'redis.connection.HiredisParser',
            'PASSWORD': redis_url.password
        }
    }
}
```

On the homepage, about 25 thumbnails are shown. But the memory jumps also on a page where only one image is shown.

Current versions:
Django==1.8.17
django-imagekit==4.0.2

Is such high memory consumption expected with django-imagekit, or did I implement it wrong? I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: probably duplicated queries, heard of a similar issue. Check with the [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) what causes the problem.

Comment: If I delete all thumbnails from Cache, the memory gets back to normal. It looks to me like the problem has to with how imagekit checks if a thumbnail exists or not.